# OS X firewall blocking torrents outside of VPN

Tags: macos, security, vpn, firewall

I've seen plenty of tutorials for this around for Windows but I'm wanting to do it on OS X Yosemite. Is it possible to configure the firewall such that torrent traffic will only ever be permitted when I'm a connected to a VPN?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you can create a blocking rule using pf, that only allows traffic on the the port your torrent software is using, to/from the virtual interface created by the VPN. Take a look at [a cheat sheet for pf](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/a-cheat-sheet-for-using-pf-in-os-x-lion-and-up/) for ideas. Or if you prefer a GUI you might check out [icefloor](http://www.hanynet.com/icefloor/).